# Use a PHP socket that is already open

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I have a server that is running a PHP UDP socket. How can I use `socket_sendto` if the socket is already open? The socket is created on the file that is running non-stop and I want to use that connection on another file.

```
socket_sendto($sock, "OFF" . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
```

Comment: Have you read  that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php. `socket_sendto` Sends a message to a socket, whether it is connected or not

Comment: my question is how can i use $sock in any file if it's already created and open

Comment: Are you using any framework or simple core php?

Comment: simple core php